# Should I move columns on a wide mysql table to the left if they are used often?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql user table that is around 35 columns wide, I notice that the things I query for most often, picture_url, username, onlinestatus are located on the far right side of the table.  Would it be better performance to have the most used items be at the very beginning of the table?

Comment: The answer probably also depends on the type of table you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column position makes no difference at all to performance in any MySQL storage engine.  When you read any column from a row, you have already incurred the most expensive part, which is the I/O of seeking and reading that row from the data file on disk.

If you want to improve performance of frequently-used columns, uses indexes.  Also learn about [covering indexes](http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/6949.html) which allow queries to read a column's value from the index without having to also read the rest of the row from the table storage.  But this also has nothing to do with the ordinal position of the column.

One more tip about columns and performance: if your query only needs a subset of the columns, don't use `SELECT *`.  Transferring all the columns over the network to your application *does* have a cost, and if you don't need all the columns, don't fetch them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  My queriers and tables are optimized to the max, I have been working on them for a couple of years now, I just read that moving the most often accessed columns to the beginning was better so I wanted to ask others about it

Comment: I am not sure, I believe it was something like google or facebook talking about performance

Comment: Well I'm certain this claim is false, I was just curious who was making it.  Even if the difference is non-zero, I guarantee that there are other things you could improve with much greater benefit -- even though you say you have "optimized to the max."